# What status code to use when certifying an upload?

Tags: http, rest, redirect, jersey

I'm working on a direct-to-S3 upload service that operates in two parts described below.  This service would not be used by browsers, but would be a RESTful API used by other software clients.

1. Make a request to an endpoint which certifies and validates the upload, returning an upload URL if all's well.
2. Make a `PUT` request to the URL returned from #1 to actually do the upload to S3.

How should the server structure the response for the first endpoint?

The first option I am considering would be to use `GET` and return a status code 302 with a `Content-Location` header containing the URL to upload to.  However, the intent behind the redirect descriptions in the spec seems to be focussed on redirecting after a form submission.

The other option I'm considering is to use `POST` for the first endpoint and returning a `Location` header with the URL, as described here:

> If a resource has been created on the origin server, the response
>   SHOULD be 201 (Created) and contain an entity which describes the
>   status of the request and refers to the new resource, and a Location
>   header. [RFC 2616 #9.5](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5)

Please advise on what other people have used in such circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it mainly depends on whether your API itself will have a resource referencing the uploaded file or not. The only one with knowledge of the uploaded file is the S3 itself or your API has something referencing it?

If the first case where only S3 knows about it, then it's OK to use the `GET` if it acts merely as a generator for the upload parameters, including the URI.

If the second case, then it shouldn't be a `GET`, since you're changing something on your side. Yes, you should make a `POST`, but the `Location` header should be used to return the URI for the created resource that references the uploaded file. That resource may have the upload URI and it could act like a state-machine, tracking if the file is uploaded or not. To avoid the need for clients to GET that resource before being able to upload, you may return the upload URI in the `Link` header, with a `rel` reflecting that purpose.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up going the route of using a POST returning a code of 201.